# What does ThrowableInformation getThrowableStrRep() do?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

It's not [documented](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation.html#getThrowableStrRep%28%29). Why does it return an array of strings? (If it had return a string, I wouldn't have asked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it says on the page you link to:

> ThrowableInformation is log4j's internal representation of throwables.
>   It essentially consists of a string array, called 'rep', where the
>   first element, that is rep[0], represents the string representation of
>   the throwable (i.e. the value you get when you do
>   throwable.toString()) and subsequent elements correspond the stack
>   trace with the top most entry of the stack corresponding to the second
>   entry of the 'rep' array that is rep[1].

Comment: Sorry I missed it, I was looking at the method documentation.